# Как сделать popup с регистрацией на wp?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить на wp сайт c woocommerce popup с регистрацией без использования плагина. В интернете полно мусора на данную тему и 80% предлогают ставит еще плагины. Аторизацию сумел прикрутить родную из wp.
Поля: имя, email пароляи повторение пароля

Comment: Так в чем проблема? посмотри исходники плагинов.... и по примеру реализуй.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Возьмите любой плагин для модалок (если сайт на бутстрапе, то они у вас уже есть). Добавляйте его на сайт при помощи `wp_enqueue_script`. Это может быть [prettyPopin](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettypopin/), например.
2. Создайте страницу через админку WordPress, например со слагом `/access/`
3. Сделайте шаблон с формой внутри файла `page-access.php` в вашей теме
4. Добавьте на сайт ссылку/кнопку (в шапку/сайдбар), которая открывает вашу модалку ajax'ом по урлу `/access/`

Всё)

Саму форму отправляйте на стандартную страницу логина WordPress. Адрес можно получить при помощи функции [wp_login_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url)